# How do Stein and Jax merge to become Firestorm?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, legends-of-tomorrow

What is the concept behind the *Firestorm* used by Professor Stein and Ronnie/Jax; i.e. how does the Firestorm work? And how do they merge with each other?

It would be helpful if someone could explain the concept deeply.

Thanks to those giving time to this question.

Comment: What do you mean by concept? Do you mean the in-universe explanation? If so, can you edit your question to something like `how is the "merging" of Firestorm explained in-universe?`

Comment: I mean that how it works

Comment: It'll be *quantum something*....I just know it will.

Comment: [Like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zVUoT2XFdE4)

Comment: @SagarMishra - the answer is most likely technobabble, so the specifics usually are not terribly important or noteworthy.  I know in the original comic series for Firestorm the same mechanic was used, and they seemed to understand it just as little then, to the point they had to work to figure out that a 3rd person was involved in the merging.  That said, the question can hang out until someone else posts an answer, it just may not be immediately.

Comment: I thought the Flash episodes that went into the "detail" of it were about all the specific info available. It was technobabble, certainly, but as self consistent as that kind of thing gets. I haven't seen that the LoT narrative requires the explanation be repeated.

Comment: @Seeds: IIRC, the details in the Flash season 2 are that they are "compatible". This is "reexplained" maybe in the episode where the Russian femal scientist try to steal the FireStorm technology. Except that, probably nothing.

Comment: They go into a bit more detail with original firestorm origin story; after the first fellow is gone, they figure out that the professor cannot go it alone, and look for a compatible replacement.

Comment: Looks like eps 12 & 13 for the original,

Comment: Which eps 12 & 13? Of which season?

Answer (score 3):

### [Paulie_D called it](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/154794/how-do-stein-and-jax-merge-to-become-firestorm/213944#comment402817_154794). Quantum Splicing.

As Caitlin explains it to Stein:

> A quantum splicer, a fission device designed to bombard your atoms with as much energy as they experience inside the particle accelerator explosion. - Flash S1E13

This device basically can cause or reverse the results of the particle accelerator explosion which happened to Stein and Raymond, allowing them to merge and separate as needed.

We see many different abilities that people receive from the particle accelerator explosion, some of them are circumstantial or environmental (Weather Wizard gets power over weather because he was in a storm at the time). Presumably because Raymond was in the accelerator, his atoms got scattered, and then found a compatible host with Stein to create the entity Firestorm.

If you are asking for a scientific explanation, this is science *fiction*, please check your science at the door.

Comment: Of course it was quantum. We all know quantum is basically magic, right?

Comment: So it's really a quantum leap?